how to build react native expo app that uses .env file
I have developed an application with react-native expo that sends requests to a server for various queries. The requests to the server work perfectly in development but when I build the application it doesn't seem to find the url for the server.
The url is defined in .env file:
EXPO_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=https://-------.com/

This is the eas.json:
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 7.8.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL": "https://------.com/"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "env": {
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL": "https://------.onrender.com/"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

I used  eas build -p android --profile preview to build the application and downloaded the app from expo to test it before submitting in to playstore.

Your preview profile uses the default url from the .env file.
